Query Performance Issue in oracle to Azure SQL Server migration
I am working on SQL Query which runs in oracle for 2 sec but in Azure SQL server running for 45 mins from hibernate Java. upon investigations here are details, finding and steps taken

Query Have 45 tables, and all tables are joined with left outer join (application need that data)
Azure optimizer is not picking up right plan
did not helped - Collected stats and execute indexoptimize procedure on full database
did not helped - Executed with multiple setting of MAXDOP
did not helped - Enabled OPTIMIZE_FOR_AD_HOC_WORKLOADS and LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION

FIX
By Adding index seek and force order hints - i am able to execute SQL in less than 2 sec. As we migrated all indexes from oracle to Azure SQL Server - appropiate indexes are in system but SQL optimizer using index scan in place of index seek scan.
Limitation:

Force plan limitation – force plan does not work if query ID is different for SQL, I did not get any post/suggestion on how to get same query id for application query.
Table Hints cannot be used in Application Code - I can fix query by using table hints, but it is not supported in Java hibernate.

Any suggestion how to fix query as with limitation

To offer a solution we'd need to see what the root problem is. For us to be able to do that, we'd need to see the actual execution plan of the query which you can upload to Paste The Plan and then link in your Post.

For plan forcing and hinting use Query Store: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/optimized-plan-forcing-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/query-store-hints?view=sql-server-ver16
